# GNU Smalltalk image save state

Tags: gnu-smalltalk

Working thro the guide making a new class.
I can make a new or load an image file (.im) using gst command.
I type in the code to make a Account class and can make a new class.

Question How do I save the class to the loaded image before closing gst window.

Next time I run gst the Account class is gone, and any instance, (a := Account new) I made is also gone.

Comment: I'm not a GNU user, but I would try `ObjectMemory snapshot`.

Comment: thanks for answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Did it work?

Comment: Yes did work but cannot figure out how to green tick your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to save the image is by sending the message

```
ObjectMemory snapshot
```